# How to resume a Linux screen session?

Tags: linux, display

```
 [ec2-user@localhost ~]$ screen -r
 There is a screen on:
         30234.tcpdump   (Attached)
 There is no screen to be resumed matching 30234.tcpdump.
 [ec2-user@localhost ~]$
```

How can I get back into this screen session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
screen -rd
```

You need to add the -d (detach) because it is attached somewhere else.

If you had more (attached) screens, you would then do:

```
 screen -rd [screen_id]
```

In your case: 30234.tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

`screen -r 30234.tcpdump`

Comment: Why will it work?